# How to find all adequate terms in a prolog database?

Tags: database, prolog

I have a database containing the following terms:

```
movie(american_beauty, 1999).
director(american_beauty, sam_mendes).
actor(american_beauty, kevin_spacey, lester_burnham).
actress(american_beauty, annette_bening, carolyn_burnham).
actress(american_beauty, thora_birch, jane_burnham).
movie(anna, 1987).
director(anna, yurek_bogayevicz).
actress(anna, sally_kirkland, anna).
actor(anna, robert_fields, daniel).
actress(anna, paulina_porizkova, krystyna).
movie(barton_fink, 1991).
director(barton_fink, ethan_coen).
director(barton_fink, joel_coen).
actor(barton_fink, john_turturro, barton_fink).
...
```

How to find all actors and actresses who play in one movie only?

How can I iterate through all the database or collect all data with recursion?

I can tell if an actor or actress plays in a given movie with:

```
plays(Actor,Movie):-
    actor(Movie,Actor,_).

plays(Actor,Movie):-
    actress(Movie,Actor,_).
```

I wold like to write a function such as:

```
how_many_movies(actor,number):-
```

and iterate through the actors and actresses, find how many movies do they play

in and print only those who have one movie. How can I do it? Or is it a wrong direction?

Comment: Hint: if a person only played in _one_ movie, then there exists no *other* movie with that actor. So you should check if another movie exists.

Comment: How can I find that one movie and then check if another movie exists? I don't know how can I write such a function that lists all the possible results. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. First acting/2 interfaces to actor/2 and actress/3.
The predicate oneFilmActor/1 first states that F is the film that Actor is playing.
oneFilmActor/2 holds when there is no other film Actor is playing.

```
acting(Film, Actor):-
    (actor(Film, Actor, _); actress(Film, Actor, _)).
    
oneFilmActor(Actor) :-
    acting(F,Actor), oneFilmActor(F, Actor).

    oneFilmActor(F, Actor) :-
        acting(F1,Actor) , F1 \= F, !, 1 \= 1. % i.e. fails
    oneFilmActor(F, Actor) :-
        true.
```

The results are, after declaring a second film for sally_kirkland by adding a clause like actress(barton_fink, sally_kirkland, any). :

```
?- oneFilmActor(A).
A = kevin_spacey ;
A = robert_fields ;
A = john_turturro ;
A = annette_bening ;
A = thora_birch ;
A = paulina_porizkova ;
```

Check that sally_kirkland is not in that list.

Comment: Can you explain your solution a little bit more detailed, please? How does oneFilmActor work? What does '!'  and '1\=1' do?

Comment: Prolog has the standard `\+` for negation, you don't need to roll your own: `acting(UniqueFilm, Actor), \+ (acting(OtherFilm, Actor), UniqueFilm \= OtherFilm)` is simpler. Even if you want to use the cut-fail idiom to implement negation, you can spell it as `!, fail` rather than inventing your own failing goal.

Comment: This code still gives me only one actor, who plays only in one movie. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ann check your data. In my ex. I did add a second film to sally_kirkland and she didn't appear in the last query.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie you are right. I tried not/1 and didn't find it...

Comment: @Ann, yes the code returns one actor at a time, and backtracks over other possibilities. If you want all of them at the same time, use bagof/3.

Answer (score 1):

One idea for writing `how_many_movies` is to first find a list of all of the movies that the actor has been in, and then find the length of that list.

You might want to try the `bagof` or `setof` predicates, which are useful for building a list of the values that can satisfy a given predicate.  The predicates `bagof` and `setof` do the same thing, except that `setof` will sort the results and remove any duplicates.

For example:

```
bagof(D, director(barton_fink, D), Directors).
```

will result in `Directors` being unified with a list of the possible values for `D` that would satisfy `director(barton_fink, D)`, which would be the different directors of that movie, namely `[ethan_coen, joel_coen]`.